# Magento product page, adding weird spaces

Tags: html, magento

I am trying to add new products on magento, it's adding weird spaces in specification section.
How do I remove this weird spaces? webpage link is below :

http://www.perisale.com.au/products/security-and-biometric-products-1/security-alarm-systems/ness-d8x-navigator-panel-kit.html

Comment: This question is off-topic because it is about using/configuring an eCommerce package, not about programming.

Comment: @JimGarrison The unwanted spacing comes from invalid html syntax, so this is probably not off-topic

Comment: In that case you should show the HTML.  Links to outside resources go stale, making the question useless to future visitors.  SO is about BOTH solving your problem and being useful to future seekers.

Answer (score 1):

Your html syntax is wrong, if you look into your html source code, in the `table` element after `<h2>Specifications :</h2>`,
 there are `br` elements laying directly after the closing tags of `tbody`, `tr`, `td` elements, this is where are unwanted spaces come from.

Demo: [Original Page](http://jsfiddle.net/3w0j2zaz/) | [Fixed Page](http://jsfiddle.net/3w0j2zaz/1/)

In order to fix your issue, you have to remove all the invalid `<br/>` from your source code. For example, you should have:

```
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><p><strong><strong>Navigator Touch Screen</strong></strong></p></td>
      <td><br /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    ...
```

Instead of:

```
<table><br />
  <tbody><br />
    <tr><br />
      <td><p><strong><strong>Navigator Touch Screen</strong></strong></p></td><br />
      <td><br /></td><br />
    </tr><br />
    <tr><br />
    ....
```

Comment: The funny thing is, in html code there are no <br> tags, magento is adding it automatically.

Comment: I have no idea how magento actually works, will there be some sort of WYSIWYG editor in the backend where the admin can input info about the product? If this is the case, the problem may be caused by the editor, which wrongly insert some invalid HTML code for the `table` element. Try to enter valid HTML code for the `table` manually instead of relying the editor.